# ASP.NET - Download File When File Name Contain Spaces

Tags: asp.net

I want to download the files from server. When downloading i want to change the file name.
But I can't change the file name totally when the filename contains spaces.

My Code is as Below

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
```

This lets the user save the file to their computer. 
But when i save the file, only the first word of the filename is saved.

eg. I want to give the file name as ("CCNA Q&A.pdf") but the file save as ("CCNA")

I want to know how to save the filename with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

in firefox: `Server.UrlEncode()` will replace space with %20
just put the filename between double quotes `filename = "\"" + filename + "\"";`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Server.UrlEncode()?
Or you can omit all non alphabetic characters (' ', -, etc) whith _-s (regular expression replace).

---

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
```

Comment: i tried httputility.urlencode. it saved all filename and extension but put + in spaces and %26 in & (CCNA Q&A.pdf) is like (CCNA+Q%26A.pdf). Anyway to save spaces as well?

Comment: i use visual studio 2008, vb.net. the following is my code.
            
context.Response.Buffer = True
context.Response.Clear()
context.Response.ContentType = "octet/stream"
'This is my code that saved only the word before space
'context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName)
'This is my new code that saved full name with plus signs in spaces
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(FileName))

context.Response.WriteFile("App_Data\" & FileName)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as I was trying to download a text file having spaces in its name. I have solved this using UrlDecode function. As browser converts spaces to '+' symbol, using decode function one need to convert these '+' to spaces.

```
fileName = Server.UrlDecode(fileName);
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to wrap it in additional quotes:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```